# Retrieve a value from JSON response

Tags: json, jsonresponse

The JSON response looks something like this

```
[
  {
    "name": 0,
    "age": 0,
  }
]
```

I created a JSON object and tried to create a JSON array

```
JSONObject myjson = new JSONObject(res.asString());
JSONArray resArray = myjson.getJSONArray("");
JSONObject response2 = resArray.getJSONObject(0);
int actualPridId_int = ((ResponseBodyExtractionOptions) response2).jsonPath().get("name");
```

There is nothing between `[` and `{` in the JSON response.

Comment: Is this code Java?

Comment: Which languague the code is? Tag your question appropriately.

Comment: Yes. The code is in Java.